# How to execute a shell script when system time is changed?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, script

I want to be able to reliably run a script on system time change.

I don't know much shell scripting, so was thinking of `touch`ing a file in a continuous loop and figuring out system time change using the file's created timestamp.

How can this be done (preferably portably)?

Comment: This is not a well-formulated question. System time changes all the time, at a rate of 1sec/sec.  There are many different ways to reset/adjust/syncrhonize system time; also there are two different `system time`s, hardware clock and software clock.  Until you have specified what it is that you want to do, it will be difficult to answer this question. You should try to explain why you want to run this script.  Unitl then, I vote to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which command will be used to change the time (`date`, `ntpdate`, ...), you can do a wrapper script for them, so they would call the *real* script plus the commands that you want to run.